# Does any one know about IE8 compatibility of knockout postbox library

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Does the knockout-postbox work with Internet Explorer 8 or 7? What updates can be made to the library to make it compatible with Internet Explorer 8 and 7?

[knockout] (http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.postbox` uses `ko.toJSON` which uses `JSON.stringify` which is not available in older browsers.

You would want to include the `json2.js` [script](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) as well to add this functionality.

This should work in IE8 already though. Is it just IE7 or what error are you seeing in IE8?